# Recommended way to login to a website through an application

Tags: android, android-webview

My application has to login to a website by posting a form, and keep track of the cookie provided till the application is terminated.

I have achieved this using the "WebView" class. I have doubts on weather this is the most efficient way to achieve this as I do not wish to display any webpages but Simply submitting another form once logged in.

Is their any other solution/Classes that can handle this with less traffic (smaller footprint)?

Comment: I would get familiar with Oauth2 and use native forms :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit data to the login form just as you can to any other.

Using the HTTP library you can add a payload (of type x-www-form-encoded) to a RequestEntity. The JavaDocs are fairly clear on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, HTTP library looks more appropriate. I'll give it a try.